# WordPress is not calling the default jQuery file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, datatables

I'm trying to call jQuery DataTable JS file for my plugin that uses DataTable to display the query from the database. The JS file is stored locally on the server.

WordPress: v4.0.1
jQuery: v1.11.1
DataTable: v1.10.5

The WordPress default jQuery file is not getting called. When I register and call the jQuery file hosted on Google, it seems to work. Is there a reason why this is happening?

Here is what I have so far:

functions.php:

```
function load_jquery_datatables() {
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
    wp_register_script( 'jquery-datatables', plugins_url('js/jquery.dataTables.min.js'), array('jquery'));
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery-datatables');
}
```

index.php:

```
<?php add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_jquery_datatables');?>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#example').DataTable();
    });
</script>

<table id="example" class="display">
            <form>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <td style="text-align: center;"><input type="checkbox" id="selectall"></td>
                    <?php
                    foreach ( $wpdb->get_col( "DESC " . $table_name, 0 ) as $column_name ) 
                    {
                        echo '<th style="text-align: center;">' . $column_name . '</th>';
                    }
                    ?>
                </tr>
            </thead>

            <tfoot>
                <tr>
                    <td style="text-align: center;"><input type="checkbox" id="selectall"></td>
                    <?php
                    foreach ( $wpdb->get_col( "DESC " . $table_name, 0 ) as $column_name ) 
                    {
                        echo '<th style="text-align: center;">' . $column_name . '</th>';
                    }
                    ?>
                </tr>
            </tfoot>
            <tbody>
                <?php
                foreach ( $results as $row ) 
                {
                    echo '<tr>';
                        echo '<td><input type=\'checkbox\' class=\'check\' value=' . $id . '></td>';
                        echo '<td>' . $row->id . '</td>';
                        echo '<td>' . $row->status . '</td>';
                        echo '<td>' . $row->create_time . '</td>';
                        echo '<td>' . $row->start_time . '</td>';
                        echo '<td>' . $row->duration . '</td>';
                        echo '<td>' . $row->source . '</td>';
                        echo '<td>' . $row->source_id . '</td>';
                    echo '</tr>';
                }
                    ?>
            </tbody>
</form>
    </table>
```

Comment: View the source, and check if the scripts are loaded *before* the script tag that calls `dataTable` and open the console and check for errors.

Comment: Put the add_action statement in functions.php right after the function definition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following change fixed the issue:

Changing the jQuery in index.php from:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#example').DataTable();
    });
</script>
```

to the following:

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        $('#example').DataTable();
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's been awhile since I have created a WordPress theme but I always used this method and it worked great!

**FUNCTIONS.PHP**

```
function custom_function_name() {
     wp_enqueue_script("jquery");
     wp_head(); ?>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo("template_url"); ?>/js/yourScript.js"></script><?php 
}
```

Call to action in your **HEADER.PHP NOT INDEX.PHP**

```
<head>
     // Link stylesheets and page titles
     // Call your function
     <?php custom_function_name(); ?>
     <script>
         $(document).ready(function() {
             $('#example').DataTable();
         });
     </script>
</head>
```